# How to export large Code Map image in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, export, diagram, visual-studio-2017, code-map

When I'm trying to save large diagram as an image:

[image: Image export in CodeMap]

Visual Studio performs memory optimization and copies image in a lower scale. Other pixels are black:

[image: clipboard after "Copy Image" action]

Is there's a way how I can easily get my diagram in a high resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution:

1. setup the zoom to max
2. save your codemap
3. than copy the image

you can paste it in paint or what ever.

[image]

Comment: Question is about very big diagrams

Answer (score 0):

What do you do it for? You can save it as vector XPS image and it will be looking nice. It can be opened on Windows PCs and printed on the paper.

[image: Code Map as XPS]